# Can reverting/resetting BIOS Settings completely erase all your xmp/memory frequency changes right?

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, bios, xmp

I was just wondering if a simple "Reset To Optimized Default" can be really impactful or effective to reverting all the changes you did.

Like for example, you turned on XMP, but then you changed your mind and changed The XMP Profile/Version, Changing Memory Frequency, etc. BUT can doing a "Reset To Optimized Defaults" Be that really effective/enough for you to fully revert to the settings you had before you even fiddled with your memory frequency and xmp settings? Or would it still be able to affect your PC in some way shape or form even when you booted up into windows normally even though you loaded the BIOS settings to "Reset to Optimized Defaults." Or you might aswell just do a CMOS Battery reset? No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting BIOS to Defaults will change back to default any setting you made.  This allows correction to changes and to remove harmful effects of changes.

Resetting CMOS is not in any way the same as resetting BIOS. So it does not do the same thing.

I keep good records of changes I make (few changes) so I can add back carefully.

Resetting CMOS:

[Resetting CMOS](https://www.velocitymicro.com/blog/what-is-cmos-and-how-to-reset/#:%7E:text=Resetting%20the%20CMOS%20chip%20involves,by%20a%20corrupted%20CMOS%20chip.)

> Resetting the CMOS chip involves clearing all the data stored in it,
> including the BIOS settings. This will revert the system to its
> default hardware configuration, which can fix any errors caused by a
> corrupted CMOS chip

I have frequently updated BIOS. I had one machine that needed BIOS to be reset to defaults to start after a BIOS update. I have never had to reset CMOS .

You only need to reset CMOS if there are CMOS errors.

I have answered your question as you put it to us. If there are computer errors. you need to have the computer serviced.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147707/discussion-on-answer-by-john-can-reverting-resetting-bios-settings-completely-er); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

A BIOS reset (aka "restore factory defaults") will erase **all**
user-defined BIOS settings and will return all settings to the
factory-default values. This is its definition and its function.

This also includes if you have applied an XMP profile to run your
system memory at different settings.

To note that a BIOS *update* may also erase the CMOS data,
which is why extreme caution should used when doing a BIOS update,
although it's nowadays becoming much safer.